# MongoDB - return whole parent dosument and single array element matching criteria

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have following MongoDB schemes:

```
{

    local            : {
        email        : String, // user's email
        name         : String, // user's name

        rooms        : [{name: String, password: String}]
    }
}
```

I have to perform query by room name (rooms.name) and get back as result entire parent document and ONLY one array element, matching the criteria `(rooms.name == 'room name')`
Room names are unique within the entire database, so I don't have to worry about this.

What I achieve so far is:

```
db.users.find({"local.rooms.name": "myroomname"}, {_id: 0, 'local.rooms.$': 1})
```

however the above query returns ONLY the array element matching the criteria, but not its parent document.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include other fields explicitly.

```
db.users.findOne({"local.rooms.name":"myroomname"},{_id:0, "local.rooms.$":1, "local.email":1, "local.name":1});
```